# Find a String and list its corresponding values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to work out on a formula in Excel. I will try and explain the same to the community here.

I have a table as below:

```
Age    Gender     Name      Location
21     Male       Andrew     Austin
25     Male       Mike       LA
27     Female     Marian     LA
23     Female     Sara       NY
24     Male       Terry      NJ
```

Now I want to put a search on the Gender and put all the other data fields in an array so that I get the results as below:

3 Queries in 3 different tabs:

- Search "Male" and display corresponding Age
- Search "Male" and display corresponding Name
- Search "Male" and display corresponding Location

Expected Output:

Search "Male" and display corresponding Age
21
25
24

Search "Male" and display corresponding Name
Andrew
Mike
Terry

Search "Male" and display corresponding Location
Austin
LA
NJ

I hope the query is clear, if not then please let me know. I am trying to do all these in Excel. In Google Sheet it is very easy to do it but struggling in Excel.

Thanks

Tried with VLOOKUP but not able to get the array result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6=$F$2,ROW($B$2:$B$6),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Formula in `H1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$6,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6=$F$2,ROW($B$2:$B$6),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Formula in `I1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$6,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6=$F$2,ROW($B$2:$B$6),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Confirm them all through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

***Female:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. However I tried the same in my sheet and its not working. Am I doing anything wrong? I am also not able to add the add the screen shot.

Comment: Have you confirmed as array formulas?

Comment: Yes I did Cltr + Shift + Enter

Comment: I dont know how to add the screen shot or else I would have shown you the screen shot.

Comment: Then please show me a screenshot and your exact used formula in `G2`. Put a link into your question and I will edit it for you to make it show.

Comment: I have not done it at G2 but somewhere random for checking. Below is my formula:

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($F$115:$F$118,SMALL(IF($G$115:$G$118=$H$111,ROW($G$115:$G$118),""),ROW(1:1))),"")

Comment: @SuvajitDas, that formula is different than what I gave you. Please notice that the start row of the index is one lower than the rest of the ranges! e.g. `INDEX($D$1:$D$6` and `...$B$2:$B$6...`

Comment: My bad i now modified it and still not working =IFERROR(INDEX($F$114:$F$118,SMALL(IF($G$115:$G$118=$H$111,ROW($G$115:$G$118),""),ROW(1:1))),"")

Comment: Without a screenshot it's hard to tell what went wrong, but my guess is that you didn''t enter it as an array formula the way you should.

Comment: How do i send you the screen shot please? Can you provide your email id or mail me at sd0038825@gmail.com

Comment: Just opload a screenshot and share the link in a comment.